# Restarting django-q qcluster gracefully

Tags: django, django-q

How can we restart qcluster gracefully for server changes? E.g. We use gunicorn to run django server which lets you gracefully restart workers without down time. How can you restart qcluster workers without disturbing any ongoing worker processing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to restart Django-Q gracefully using the `kill -SIGHUB` since it is a convention for restarting services gracefully but it didn't work. I noticed Django-Q restart gracefully when receiving CTRL+C command and from there I found the solution.

```sh
# -2 is SIGINT. It acts like CTRL+C.
pkill -e -2 --full 'python manage.py qcluster';  (python manage.py qcluster &)
```

Comment: "I noticed Django-Q restart gracefully when receiving CTRL+C" - don't you mean " I noticed Django-Q *stops* gracefully when receiving CTRL+C" ? That's what I see on MacOS. Ctrl-C also causes a clean shutdown.